# ListActivity not started unless I leave the app and come back

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, listactivity

Have an Android app that is working fine on Android 2.3.6 devices and all 4.x virtual devices. However I've gotten reports from a user that on several devices running 4.0.4 - 4.1.1 one activity doesn't show up unless you go to another app and return again. I've tried everything I can think of but it doesn't make any difference and I since I can't reproduce the bug on virtual devices I can't debug (nor test) it myself. Here is a video clip showing what happens for this user: [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yfwHMNjXctk)

The calling of the activity that doesn't show is this:

```
Intent stationList = new Intent(LoggedIn.this, StationList.class);
  stationList.putExtra("stationlist", stationlist);
startActivityForResult(stationList, 1);
```

The contents of the station list activity:

```
public class StationList extends ListActivity {

private ListView list ;  
  private ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter ;

  @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
      if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)

          {
          Intent returnIntent = new Intent();

       setResult(RESULT_CANCELED,returnIntent);     
       finish();    

          }
        return true;
    }

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.list);

    // Find the ListView resource.   
    list = (ListView) findViewById( android.R.id.list );  

    // Create and populate a List of stations.  
     String stationlist = getIntent().getExtras().getString("stationlist");

    final String[] stationListArray = stationlist.split("\n");

    ArrayList<String> stationList = new ArrayList<String>();  
    stationList.addAll( Arrays.asList(stationListArray) );  


    // Create ArrayAdapter using the station list.  
    listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(StationList.this, R.layout.simplerow, stationList);  


    // Set the ArrayAdapter as the ListView's adapter.  
    list.setAdapter( listAdapter ); 



    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> list, View view, 
             int position, long id) { 
           // Get the cursor, positioned to the corresponding row in the result set
               String channel = "echo -n 'notempty' > ~/.config/pianobar/stationcreate && echo '" + position + "' >> ~/.config/pianobar/ctl";
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                         "Starting station " + stationListArray[position] +", please wait", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    


               Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
               returnIntent.putExtra("channel",channel);
               setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);     
               finish();            

           }
          });


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_station_list, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

List.xml:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="horizontal"
 tools:context=".StationList" >
 <ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent"   
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"   
   android:id="@android:id/list">  
 </ListView>  
<TextView
      android:id="@android:id/empty"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:text="Loading station data..." />
</LinearLayout>
```

Simplerow.xml:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
android:id="@+id/rowTextView"   
android:layout_width="fill_parent"   
android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
android:padding="10dp"  
android:textSize="16sp" >  
</TextView>
```

Comment: are you getting any crashes ?

Comment: No, no crashes (unfortunately).

Comment: There will be because I tried it and its working fine for me :)

Comment: The code is working for you? What Android version did you test it under?

Comment: which one you are using ?

Comment: I'm using 2.3.6 on my phone and it's working fine there, same with the 4.0.4 SDK. The user who is having problems has tried it with 4.0.4 and 4.1.1 on 4 different devices.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/q6ci3.png I ma getting this and its working fine on android 4.1

Comment: Ok, thanks. Good to know :) Still don't understand why this apparently happens on certain devices though...

Comment: try to get the crash log from the user's device :P

Comment: I would if there were any crashes =/

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by this code `Intent returnIntent = new Intent();returnIntent.putExtra("channel",channel);           setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);`? Can you brief you question ?

Comment: When you select a station in the station list it will go back to the first activity and send a command that will start the selected station. This works fine, also for the user who is having problems (after getting the station list by leaving the app and returning).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured this out, it was actually caused by a long running asynctask. As long as the doInBackground was running it wouldn't start the ListActivity - when you switch to another app the doInBackground would stop and the ListActivity would be brought up. Sorted it out by moving the stuff that was handled in the asynctask to a thread/handler instead.